# How to highlight the current day on "android material-calendar"

Tags: android, calendar

I am using material-calendar for android
https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

```
materialCalender = (MaterialCalendarView)v.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    materialCalender.state().edit()
            .setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY)
            .setMinimumDate(CalendarDay.from(1900, 1, 1))
            .setMaximumDate(CalendarDay.from(2100, 12, 31))
            .setCalendarDisplayMode(CalendarMode.MONTHS)
            .commit();
```

but the calender doesn't show the current day on the calender view.
so, how to show that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set a different color for the current date you have to add a Decorator to your MaterialCalendarView:

```
calendarView.addDecorator(new DayViewDecorator() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
        Calendar cal1 = day.getCalendar();
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

        return (cal1.get(Calendar.ERA) == cal2.get(Calendar.ERA)
                && cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                && cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == 
               cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this,R.drawable.selector));
    }
});
```

Where selector is your custom selector.xml, for example:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime">

 <item
 android:state_checked="true"
 android:drawable="@color/yourColor"
 />

<item
android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@color/yourColor"
/>

<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Selector Reference Link: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/CUSTOM_SELECTORS.md

Decorator Reference Link: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/DECORATORS.md

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
    MaterialCalendarView materialCalView = findViewById(R.id.ID_from_your_xml_code);
    materialCalView.setDateSelected(CalendarDay.today(), true);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.

Comment: thanks for reply L_J i edited the text , but to be honest i cant give good description how its work , cause im new in android

Comment: date was shown inside the calendar.
But the previous left selection also rested there.

Answer (score 1):

```
MaterialCalendarView materialCalendarView=(MaterialCalendarView) findViewById (R.id.calendarView);     
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
materialCalendarView.setDateSelected(calendar.getTime(), true);
```

I hope this might help you

Answer (score -1):

> I am setting firstDayOfWeek as below

```
mcv = (MaterialCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
mcv.state().edit()
           .setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY)
           .commit();
```

Comment: no I am talking about the current day, e.g, today is Friday, it should show the friday highlighted.
when I click on Sunday, the Friday color should not hide.